# Fill Form from an array

Tags: javascript, forms, fill

I would like to fill a form from an array and then to remove that element from the array.
So when I click on the 'Fill It' button - form should be filled and now array should be without that element.
The Problem is that the array is not popped, shifted or sliced and it always loads the same data into form fields.

Html form I have:

```
<h3><input class="FormControl" placeholder="Discussion Title"></h3>
<textarea class="Composer-flexible" placeholder="Write something..."  style="height: 166.2px;"></textarea>
```

My code:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Fill It";


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);


button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
var arr = 
[["title1","post1"],["title2","post2"],["title3","post3"]];
var post = arr[0][1];
var title= arr[0][0];
document.getElementsByClassName("FormControl")[0].value=title;
document.getElementsByClassName("Composer-flexible")[0].value = post;
var arr=arr.slice(1);
console.log(arr);
});
```

Fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/q1vc26oe/2/

After I fill it I have to review it a little bit and then I would submit it.
But problem occurs next time when I load html page and try to fill the same form but this time with 'title2' and 'post2' it loads 'title1' and 'post1' cause the array is not popped, shifted or sliced.How to do that?

In addition (it would be the next step when I make sure that script is running well) how to submit it, not automatically, but after 15 seconds cause I'd like to have a brief review before submitting (this is not big priority right now so you can add to your answer or not....)

Comment: "But problem occurs next time when I load html page"  Why would it do anything else?  You've reloaded the code, so it's going to reinitialize the variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I hit "fill it" button second time it should fill second element of an array but it doesn't happen...it confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your working code: -

```js
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Fill It";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);
var arr = [
  ["title1", "post1"],
  ["title2", "post2"],
  ["title3", "post3"]
];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var post = arr[0][1];
  var title = arr[0][0];
  document.getElementsByClassName("FormControl")[0].value = title;
  document.getElementsByClassName("Composer-flexible")[0].value = post;
  arr = arr.slice(1);
  console.log(arr);
});
```

You were creating a new array (named 'arr') every time on button click, so make sure you create the array only once.

And make sure you check if the array is empty on button click